# Sliding divs in and out of page view simutaniously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

Im fairly new to javascript. Ive adapted some script Ive found to do something similar to what I need but its not working as I'd like it too. I apologize for the long explanation.

I have 6 buttons, button 1 -3 responsible for the left divs, and button 4 - 6 responsible for the divs on the right.

When the script run, none of the divs should be visible.

When buttons#1 is clicked, div#1 slides out from the left and is then positioned its own width from the left of the container. This is the same for div#2 and div#3 corresponding to button#2 and button#3. Only 1 div can be seen at a time so button#2 will hide div#1 and div#3 and show div#2, ect. Same for all the other buttons.

When button#4  is clicked, div#4 slides out from the right and is positioned its own width from the right of the container. The hiding of the divs when another button is clicked is the same as the above, only 1 div can be seen at a time.

Help would greatly be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">




$(window).load(function(){

   $('.button-left').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index(".button-left");
    var $box = $(".box-left:eq(" + index + ")");

    $(".box-left").not($box).animate({
        left: '150%'
    }, 500);

    if ($box.offset().left < 0) {
        $box.css("left", "150%");
    } else if ($box.offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
        $box.animate({
            left: '25%',
        }, 500);
    }
});

    $('.button-right').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index(".button-right");
    var $box = $(".box-right:eq(" + index + ")");

    $(".box-right").not($box).animate({
        left: '150%'
    }, 500);

    if ($box.offset().left < 0) {
        $box.css("left", "150%");
    } else if ($box.offset().left > $('#container').width()) {
        $box.animate({
            left: '105%',
        }, 500);
    }
});
});




</script>
<style type="text/css">
#container {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    padding: 0px;
    width:1024px;
    height:568px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#999999;
}

.box-left {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    left: 150%;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: -25%;
}

.box-right {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid black;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: -25%;

}

#box1 {
    background-color: green;
    left:260px;
}

#box2 {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#box3 {
    background-color: red;
}

#box4 {
    background-color: orange;
    right:0px;
}

#box5 {
    background-color: purple;
}

#box6 {
    background-color: brown;
}
</style>



<div class="button-left"><a href="#">Click Box #1</a> </div>
<div class="button-left"><a href="#">Click Box #2</a> </div>
<div class="button-left"><a href="#">Click Box #3</a> </div>

<div class="button-right"><a href="#">Click Box #4</a> </div>
<div class="button-right"><a href="#">Click Box #5</a> </div>
<div class="button-right"><a href="#">Click Box #6</a> </div>


<div id="container">

    <div id="box1" class="box-left">Box #1</div>
    <div id="box2" class="box-left">Box #2</div>
    <div id="box3" class="box-left">Box #3</div>
    <div id="box4" class="box-right">Box #4</div>
    <div id="box5" class="box-right">Box #5</div>
    <div id="box6" class="box-right">Box #6</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I suggest you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) rather than asking the community to try and parse a wall of text and a wall of code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle.net/KFqvf](http://jsfiddle.net/KFqvf)

This is a jsfiddle with what I think you want in. Just needs simple jquery animate function to slide in left and right, and a simple menu to select the items!

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its not what I'm trying to achieve though :)

Comment: @undefined would it be possible for you to help me ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KFqvf/ How does that look? Is that what your trying to achieve? Full screen result here http://jsfiddle.net/KFqvf/embedded/result/ cause the right hand tabs don't show very well on the multipbox stuff. I should add this is jQuery dependent. I hope that's not an issue

Comment: Thanks @George Wilson. On this example : jsfiddle.net/KFqvf,  That's basically it, instead of fading it should slide in and slide out. how would I adapt the code to do that ?

Comment: @Charl [jsfiddle.net/KFqvf/6](http://jsfiddle.net/KFqvf/6) Is that more like it? [jsfiddle.net/KFqvf/6/embedded/result](http://jsfiddle.net/KFqvf/6/embedded/result) (Result again). Basically used the animate function in jquery rather than the fade in and fade out